# Solr: Facet Count incorrect when using Collapse and Expand Results

Tags: json, solr, facet

When using Collapse and Expand Results the Facet count returned is incorrect.
As shown in the screenshot below it should be 1212 (numFound), but it's returning 102 (some grouped value).

```
https://localhost/solr/index/select?q=*:*
&fq={!collapse+field%3Dcode_string}
&fq={!tag%3Dfk1}week_int:17
&expand=true
&expand.rows=100
&facet.field={!ex%3Dfk1}week_int
&facet=true
&facet.sort=count
&facet.mincount=1
&facet.limit=5000
```

[image]

I've tried the following options:

1. Grouping works fine - **Solution**: `group.field=code_string&group.main=true`, but I'm interested in making collapse and expand feature to work similarly as performance-wise it's more preferred way.
2. Tried `fq={!collapse+field%3Dcode_string}` and `facet.field={!ex=collapse}week_int` - Doesn't return the other facet values, it only returns the facet value added in fq which is `week_int:17`
3. `collapse.facet=facet.before|facet.after`
4. I've tried JSON facet as follows, but it doesn't return the other facet values which aren't part of fq

`

```
https://localhost/solr/index/select?q=*:*
    &fq={!collapse field=code_string}
    &fq={!tag=fk2}week_int:17
    &expand=true
    &json.facet={
      week_int: {
        type: terms,
        field: week_int,
        facet: {
          workCount: "unique(code_string)"
        },
        domain: {
          excludeTags: [code_string]
        }
      }
    }
```

`

How to get the actual facet count along with other facet values which would work usually without applying collapse?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the way you are using exclusion is not the desired way. Try tagging it before.

In your case, tag the collapse query first and then exclude it during faceting.
Something like this :-

```
https://localhost/solr/index/select?q=*:*
&fq={!tag%3Dcollapsetag}{!collapse+field%3Dcode_string}
&fq={!tag%3Dfk1}week_int:17
&expand=true
&expand.rows=100
&facet.field={!ex%3Dfk1,collapsetag}week_int
&facet=true
&facet.sort=count
&facet.mincount=1
&facet.limit=5000
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the way the data was indexed is incorrect, to fix this particular issue I had to maintain it on the document as a multivalued string field i.e `weekNumber_string_mv`.